# Input type "number" changes value if too high - But why?

Tags: html, input, numbers

I have an input field with type number:

```
<input type="number" id="cardNumber" />
```

When typing "1234567891234567" as value, the last 2 digits change and the new value becomes: "1234567891234570"

I guess it is because of a limit but does anyone know what the limit is? Maybe some official specifications stating this?

In case anyone finds this issue for at solution it would be the following for mobilephones:

```
Android: <input type="tel" id="cardNumber" />
IOS: <input type="text" id="cardNumber" pattern='[0-9]*' />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the limit is if there is any. I tried it myself in the [w3schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_number) and it seems to return the number as long as it fits in the textbox so it seems more dependent on how large the textbox is rather than the actual type number property.

It seems for your situation though you are looking to set a `max` or `min` value input type number happens to have that available as an attribute you can set. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I think it depends the the amount typed en value and not the width of the field. I just tried with a width of 1000px. Same issue.